# How do I fix the flutter error: "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'"?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using flutter on MacOS 14 and when I try to run my app with `flutter run` on an android emulator I get the following error:

```
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
e: file:///Users/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/MainActivity.kt:5:23 Conflicting import, imported name 'FlutterActivity' is ambiguous
e: file:///Users/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/MainActivity.kt:6:37 Conflicting import, imported name 'FlutterActivity' is ambiguous
e: file:///Users/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/MainActivity.kt:9:21 Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity
e: file:///Users/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/MainActivity.kt:10:5 'onCreate' overrides nothing
e: file:///Users/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/MainActivity.kt:11:15 Unresolved reference: onCreate
e: file:///Users/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/MainActivity.kt:12:48 Type mismatch: inferred type is MainActivity but FlutterEngine was expected
e: file:///Users/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/arhanbusam/simpleexercisetimer/MainActivity.kt:5:23 Conflicting import, imported name 'FlutterActivity' is ambiguous
e: file:///Users/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/arhanbusam/simpleexercisetimer/MainActivity.kt:6:37 Conflicting import, imported name 'FlutterActivity' is ambiguous
e: file:///Users/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/arhanbusam/simpleexercisetimer/MainActivity.kt:9:21 Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity
e: file:///Users/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/arhanbusam/simpleexercisetimer/MainActivity.kt:10:5 'onCreate' overrides nothing
e: file:///Users/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/arhanbusam/simpleexercisetimer/MainActivity.kt:11:15 Unresolved reference: onCreate
e: file:///Users/arhanbusam/simple_exercise_timer/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/arhanbusam/simpleexercisetimer/MainActivity.kt:12:48 Type mismatch: inferred type is MainActivity but FlutterEngine was expected
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

I tried to use `flutter clean` before running, upgrading my flutter version (3.13.5) and trying solutions I found on other stack overflow questions, non of which worked. I was expecting the app to launch normally on the emulator.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your build.gradle file in the root of your Android directory and upgrade your minSdkVersion

minSdkVersion 24

Answer (score 0):

Go to your build.gradle file in the root of your Android directory and upgrade your Kotlin_version to the latest.

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
minSdkVersion 23
```

```
plugins {
  id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
  id "com.android.application" version "7.2.2" apply false
  id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.22" apply false
  id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
}
```